# Calculate sample size (or experiment repetition no.) with unknown population

Tags: confidence-interval, experiment-design, sample-size

I am running an experiment and I would like what is a good method to calculate how many times I need to run an experiment, in other words, how many data points I will need to collect.
The issue is that I do not know my population. Theoretically speaking, I could repeat the measurement many times (assuming no budget or time/budget or other constraints).
On the other hand, I know the confidence interval that I'd like to have (95%) and a margin of error of no more than 5%

Assume no prior knowledge about the mean or standard deviation (essentially I will be running this experiment for the 1st time).

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Confidence interval for what?

Comment: For the statistic of interest (e.g. mean) for a metric.

Comment: It may be worth your time to look into [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics)). The statistical power of a hypothesis test is, among other things, related to the number data points (number of subjects in the analysis, for instance).

Comment: Hi Adam, I thought about this but I am not dealing with hypotheses in my case. I am dealing with a continuous variable.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to know how many samples you need to estimate a mean to a given precision with a given confidence but that you don't have a hypothesis to test.

To answer this, you need to do a power analysis. This requires an estimate of the standard error, which you can get from N and the standard deviation. But you need to estimate the SD. You can base this estimate on prior knowledge, a literature review or whatever, but you need to estimate it somehow.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you define power analysis. The ideas are similar. You need to estimate sd.

Comment: Hi Peter, yes, that is correct. I looked into power analysis but this approach requires having some sort of hypothesis which I don't have (and want to avoid if possible).

What I think is right for my case is the following formula for the margin of error:
$$
\text{margin of error} = z \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
where z is the [z-score or standard score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) and which I solve for n and assuming a SD from prior knowledge.

Happy to know if there are any alternative or better ways!